# How to get values from JSON

Tags: android, json

I have some data in JSON format like this:

`{"Datos":[{"cli_nombre":"Futcho 7","suc_nombre":"Naucalpan"}],"status":0,"mensaje":""}`

The status and mensaje keys are not in Datos array. How can I get it?

I can get the values to the unique Object, this object has two keys cli_nombre and suc_nombre and I don't have problems to get the values for this keys.

Regards

Comment: If you have the object, and it contains the keys and the array, just get the int from the key in the object.

Comment: Could you show the entire code where you get the values from Datos array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that JSON in a String, you could use the following code to get the status *and mensaje*:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
String mesaje = jsonObject.getString("mensaje");
```

Hope it helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the array but in the `JSONObject`.

So simply call

```
jObject.getInt("status");
```